# Eclipse WindowBuilder palette locked and gef.core error message

Tags: windowbuilder, org.eclipse.wb.gef.core

In Eclipse WindowBuilder. I added WindowBuilder to Eclipse today.
Eclipse 2023-06
When I hover over anything in the palette I am unable to choose any component. But that palette does show a hover help that says "JTabbedPane"(with desc) - regardless of what I'm hovering over or where the cursor entered the palette area.

Another odd symptom - when I change the Layout the editing frame clears for an Internal Error message for 'java.lang.Iterable org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.EditPart.getEditPolicyIterable()'

There are some questions in StackOverflow regarding a panel with missing components. But here the components are displayed, just not functioning and behaving weird.
I had expected to be able to put components onto the panel once it was displayed.
I cannot get beyond that - nothing can be added using the tool due to palette stuck problem. 
Any suggestions - how to fix or further debug this? 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from the eclipse-windowbuilder community (Thank you ptziegler!) ref
https://github.com/eclipse-windowbuilder/windowbuilder/discussions/724
Problem came down to my Eclipse (23-06) - the GEF libraries that were with that preceded an update in fall of 2023. So to get the Graphical Editing Framework up-to-date use the typical Eclipse update process with these details, which I'll mostly be summarizing and/or quoting from Mr.Ziegler's response.

1. Menubar > Help > Install New Software
2. Paste URL in the dialog https://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/classic/release/latest/
3. Select both Draw2d and GEF
   ...and then [Next] to finish up.
   The version of GEF components should be at least 3.15.+

I'm sharing here to help those who experience the same issue. More details are at the Github project link above (credit to ptziegler).

It's very likely just upgrading Eclipse to the current version would likely have fixed this too. It would have been a very inconvenient time for me to reinstall Eclipse and my other plugins at that time.